# How to deploy a REST service on glassfish under eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I've written a simple REST service class, and I need to deploy and run it under glassfish server, installed on my eclipse.

What steps have I to do in order to put this restlet service online and reach it from my browser?

This is the code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;

@Path("/myApplication")
public class MailRestlet {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public MyRestlet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getHtml() {
        return "<html><body><h1>Hello World!!</h1>The service is online!!</body></html>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to configure the web.XML file, for example, as in http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ggrby/index.html

There is also a way to avoid web.XML change, by extending the Application class from jaxrs...

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to configuring the end point using the web.xml file, you can extend the Application class as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508159/jax-rs-glassfish-eclipse-a-simple-web-service-doesnt-work/23575215#23575215).

From in Eclipse, you can deploy on the server by:

- Right clicking the project and then *Run As > Run on Server*.
- Select your server from the list of servers you have connected to Eclipse on the screen that follows and click *Next*.
- Ensure the project is listed under *Configured* and click *Finish*.
- You can also set Eclipse to automatically publish to GlassFish when you change the code. Double click the GlassFish Server on the Server view. Expand the *Publishing* expandable list and select *Automatically publish when resources change*.